# Compiling simple Opt++ example: Undefined reference to dswap_

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I downloaded [Opt++](https://software.sandia.gov/opt++/index.html).  I did the [basic install](https://software.sandia.gov/opt++/opt++2.4_doc/html/InstallDoc.html):

```
1. cd optpp-2.4
2. ./configure
3. make >& make.log
4. make check >& makecheck.log
5. make install
```

I replicated [Example 1: Unconstrained Quasi-Newton Without Derivatives](https://software.sandia.gov/opt++/opt++2.4_doc/html/example1.html) in the codes below.  But as I try to compile, i.e.

```
g++ run_rosen.cpp rosen.cpp -Wno-write-strings -DHAVE_NAMESPACES -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/lib -lopt -lnewmat
```

I get the errors below.  And I also think it's odd that there's a reference to my downloads directory.

```
//usr/local/lib/libopt.a(dqrdc.o): In function dqrdc:
/home/a/downloads/optpp-2.4/src/PDS/dqrdc.c: 156: undefind reference to dswap_
/home/a/downloads/optpp-2.4/src/PDS/dqrdc.c: 182: undefind reference to dswap_
...
//usr/local/lib/libopt.a(pdsdone.o): In function pdsdone:
/home/a/downloads/optpp-2.4/src/PDS/pdsdone.c: 128: undefind reference to dnrm2_
...
```

Codes:

run_rosen.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include "rosen.h"
#include "NLF.h"
#include "OptQNewton.h"


using namespace OPTPP;

int main()
{
    int ndim = 2;
    FDNLF1 nlp (ndim, rosen, init_rosen);
    OptQNewton objfcn(&nlp);

    objfcn.setSearchStrategy(TrustRegion);
    objfcn.setMaxFeval(200);
    objfcn.setFcnTol(1.e-4);

    if (!objfcn.setOutputFile("rosen.out", 0))
    {
        cerr << "main: output file open failed" << endl;
    }

    objfcn.optimize();
    objfcn.printStatus("Solution from quasi-newton");
    objfcn.cleanup();
}
```

rosen.h

```
#ifndef ROSEN_H
#define ROSEN_H

#include "NLF.h"
#include "OptNewton.h"

void init_rosen(int ndim, NEWMAT::ColumnVector& x);

void rosen(int ndim, const NEWMAT::ColumnVector& x, double& fx, int& result);

#endif // ROSEN_H
```

rosen.cpp

```
#include "rosen.h"

void init_rosen(int ndim, NEWMAT::ColumnVector& x)
{
    if (ndim != 2)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    x(1) = 1.2;
    x(2) = 1.0;
}

void rosen(int ndim, const NEWMAT::ColumnVector& x, double& fx, int& result)
{

    if (ndim != 2)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    double f1, f2;
    f1 = (x(2) - x(1) * x(1));
    f2 = 1. - x(1);
    fx = 100. * f1 * f1 + f2 * f2;
    result = OPTPP::NLPFunction;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link against a BLAS library.  Try adding this to the end of your build command:

```
-lblas
```

Comment: Thanks.  As a side note, do you have experience using Opt++ and other optimization libraries?  If so, do you recommend any other libraries?